# How to add or substract value if user check or uncheck checkbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have following code in javascript which performs a subtraction of multiple dynamic textbox based on checkbox check. this function works fine when user check the checkbox,but what i want is if user uncheck the check box then it should subtract unchecked checkbox sum and only show checked checkbox sum

here is html code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputfl4">Transection Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trn_no" name="trn_no" placeholder="Transection Number">
    <span style="color: red"> 
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputln4">Amount</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="">
</div>
    
<div class="form-group col-md-6">    
    <label for="inputln4">Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="autoclose-date" name="date_pay" class="datepicker-here form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
</div>
       

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="edit-btn">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" style="text-align: right; border-right-style: hidden; color: red;"><b>Amount Remaining From Transaction Amount : </b></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="color: red; text-align: left;" id="amt_total"><b></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Bill Number</th>
            <th>Vendor Name</th>
            <th>Bill To</th>
            <th>Payment Type</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Amount Remaining</th>
            <th>Amount Paid</th>
            <th style="color: red;">Amount Payable</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($search as $bill)
<td align="center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="optional" name="myTextEditBox" data-id="amt_paid" onclick="totalIt()">
                                              </td>
                                              <td>{{$bill->bill_number}}</td>
                                              <td>{{$bill->vendor_name}}</td>
                                              <td>{{$bill->bill_to}}</td>
                                              <td id="amt" class="amt">{{$bill->amount}}</td>
                                              <td id="amt_rem" class="amt_rem">{{$bill->amount_payable}}</td>
             <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="amt_paid" name="amt_paid"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="amt_pay" name="amt_pay" style="color: red; border-color: red;" readonly></td>
            <tr></tr>  
            </tr>
        @endforeach
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

```js
function totalIt() {
    var texts = document.getElementsByName("amt_paid");
    var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var n = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < texts.length; ++i){

        n += Number(texts[i].value);
        
    }
     var sum = parseInt(a) - n;
    document.getElementById("amt_total").innerHTML = sum;
    document.getElementById("amt_total").style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
```

the flow is - user enters amount in txt1 and then in amt_paid. User get the subtraction of both the fields in another inputbox (or alert box). Now if user uncheck the checkbox corresponding with amt_paid then alertbox should only show checked checkbox sum

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML.

Comment: @iota ok i have edited my question

Comment: What you provided as html is not a [mre]. There aren't even any checkboxes in that code

Comment: I just edited to make it properly indented, but you have unmatched tags (closing tags without an corresponding opening one). This can't be a working html code.

Comment: Sir the code is edited! original code has proper formatting but i messed it up here while pasting. I am new here so dont know the proper format of pasting code on stackovrflow! sorry for the inconvenience!  Now i have added the corresponding checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the sum of the values of the input elements adjacent to checked checkboxes each time the state of one of them changes.

```js
for (const checkbox of document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
    console.log('change')
    const sum = [...document
        .querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked + input[type=text]')]
        .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr.value, 0);
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = sum;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"> <input type="text"> <br>
<input type="checkbox"> <input type="text"> <br>
<input type="checkbox"> <input type="text"> <br>
<p id="output"></p>
```